# How do I change contents of a column in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, stata

I’m using data from World Development Indicators (WDI) and want to merge this data with some other data. My problem is that the spelling of country names in the two datasets is different.  How do I change the country variable?

```
library('WDI')
df <- WDI(country="all", indicator= c("NY.GDP.MKTP.CD", "EN.ATM.CO2E.KD.GD", 'SE.TER.ENRR'), start=1998, end=2011, extra=FALSE)

head(df)
      country iso2c year NY.GDP.MKTP.CD EN.ATM.CO2E.KD.GD SE.TER.ENRR
99  ArabWorld    1A 1998   575369488074          1.365953          NA
100 ArabWorld    1A 1999   627550544566          1.355583    19.54259
101 ArabWorld    1A 2000   723111925659          1.476619          NA
102 ArabWorld    1A 2001   703688747656          1.412750          NA
103 ArabWorld    1A 2002   713021728054          1.413733          NA
104 ArabWorld    1A 2003   803017236111          1.469197          NA
```

How do i change ArabWorld to Arab World?

There are a lot of names I need to change so doing this with the use of row.numbers will not give me enough flexibility. I want something that is similar to the `replace` function in Stata.

Comment: What country is Arab World? You might find the function `recode` in the `car` package useful, or changing this to a `factor` rather than a character vector and then modifying the `levels`. Other than that look at `?sub` for replacement in character vectors.

Comment: It seems the question was asking about changing a column, so I hope you don't take offense at the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work for character or factors.

```
df$country <- sub("ArabWorld", "Arab World", df$country)
```

This is equivalent:

```
> df[,1] <- sub("ArabWorld", "Arab World", df[,1] )
> head(df)
       country iso2c year NY.GDP.MKTP.CD EN.ATM.CO2E.KD.GD
99  Arab World    1A 1998   575369488074          1.365953
100 Arab World    1A 1999   627550544566          1.355583
101 Arab World    1A 2000   723111925659          1.476619
102 Arab World    1A 2001   703688747656          1.412750
```

If you create a dataframe with the desired changes you can loop through to change them. Note that I have updated this so that it shows how to enter the parentheses in that column so they would be correctly passed to `sub`:

```
name.cng <- data.frame(orig = c("AntiguaandBarbuda", "AmericanSamoa", 
                                    "EastAsia&Pacific\\(developingonly\\)",
                                    "Europe&CentralAsia\\(developingonly\\)", 
                                    "UnitedArabEmirates"), 
                           spaced=c("Antigua and Barbuda", "American Samoa",
                                    "East Asia & Pacific (developing only)",
                                     "Europe&CentralAsia (developing only)", 
                                      "United Arab Emirates") )
for (i in 1:NROW(name.cng)){ 
      df$country <- sub(name.cng[i,1], name.cng[i,2], df$country) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, especially if you have many names to change, is probably to put your correspondance table in a `data.frame`, and join it with the data, with the `merge` command.
For instance, if you wanted to change the name of the Koreas:

```
# Correspondance table
countries <- data.frame(
  iso2c = c("KR", "KP"),
  country = c("South Korea", "North Korea")
)

# Join the data.frames
d <- merge( df, countries, by="iso2c", all.x=TRUE )
# Compute the new country name
d$country <- ifelse(is.na(d$country.y), as.character(d$country.x), as.character(d$country.y))
# Remove the columns we no longer need
d <- d[, setdiff(names(d), c("country.x", "country.y"))]

# Check that the result looks correct
head(d)
head(d[ d$iso2c %in% c("KR", "KP"), ])
```

However, it may be safer to join your two datasets on the country ISO code, which is more standard, than on the country name.

Answer (score 0):

Using subsetting:

```
df[df[, "country"] == "ArabWorld", "country"] <- "Arab World"

head(df)
   country iso2c year NY.GDP.MKTP.CD EN.ATM.CO2E.KD.GD SE.TER.ENRR
99  Arab World    1A 1998   575369488074          1.365953          NA
100 Arab World    1A 1999   627550544566          1.355583    19.54259
101 Arab World    1A 2000   723111925659          1.476619          NA
102 Arab World    1A 2001   703688747656          1.412750          NA
103 Arab World    1A 2002   713021728054          1.413733          NA
104 Arab World    1A 2003   803017236111          1.469197          NA
```

Comment: In case the data contains missing values (it is not the case here, but it often happens), `df[which(df[, "country"] == "ArabWorld"), "country"]` is safer.